# Is it doable to get the private keys from a Bisq wallet?

Tags: private-key, backup, bisq

I do not mean getting the seed phrase - this I've already backed up. I do not see such a possibility from Bisq's GUI.
Is it doable to get the private key of a particular address of a Bisq wallet (much the same way as one would by executing `dumpprivkey` with **bitcoin-cli**)?

Comment: I couldn't find any command to dump private key for bisq-cli in https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/tree/b6f9231af968811e19b96c3d3137e37499b555d7/core/src/main/resources/help